# facebook page plugin is not showing in any browser because offsetWidth is null error

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I had added the facebook sdk after the body tag so I use this sdk for both (facebook login , facebook page plugin)

facebook login is working fine but the page plugin is not showing on my website in any browser.

i get this error in the console  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null`

this is the sdk that i added:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    version    : 'v2.0',
    status     : true, // check login status
    cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
  });

  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {

    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      FB.login();
    } else {
      FB.login();
     }
  });
  };

 // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
   //js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
   ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
  }(document));

  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is successful. 
  // This testAPI() function is only called in those cases. 
  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Welocme, ' + response.name + '.');
    });
  }
</script>
```

And this is the cod of the page plugin :

`<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/example" 
  data-width="380" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true"
  data-show-posts="false"></div>`

do I miss anything here? i add the sdk properly and I add also the page code properly in my website footer? why the plugin is not showing ?

NOTE : I noticed now that when I log in to my website through facebook the page plugin shows , even if I logged out the plug is still showing but when I close the browser and open again the plugin is not showing anymore with the same error in the console.

Comment: Is your Facebook page publicly available and not restricted in any way? Otherwise, the plugin will only work if the user is logged in to Facebook (because it needs that to check if the user satisfies the restrictions.)

Comment: actually I check and i think yes it was about restrictions . I should choose +13 for the age restriction . it was +18 so I changed it and now it is working fine